# Use your own RTCCertificate

Tags: webrtc, dtls

I'm have compatibility issues with WebRTC implementation and our Oracle (AcmePacket) SBC. I think I could work around the issue that they confirmed and will fix somewhere next year, by using a certificate that is signed by a CA for DTLS.

I have been looking around but couldn't find any reference: would it be possible to load my own RTCCertificate from a file?

I know that from a security perspective this is a bad idea, but it's for a proof-of-concept application, and by the time we would use this in production, the bug on the Oracle SBC would be fixed OR we can run rtpengine inbetween which would handle the self-signed random certificate correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible (in the browser). RTCPeerConnection does allow you to pass a certificate, but can only be generated using [generateCertificate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/generateCertificate)

Running a bridge I think is your only option in this case unfortunately.